# Generating random integers, but they need to be different each time

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently making a program for school work, and I need to make a maths quiz program. I'm doing a simple multiplication quiz.

I need to be able to generate 2 random integers for the questions, but they have to be different for each question.

```
import random
correct = wrong = num1 = num2 = 0
questionNum = 1
num1 = random.randint(1,49)
num2 = random.randint(50,100)

for i in range(0, 8):
    print("\nQuestion", questionNum)
    print("What is", num1, "mulitplied by", num2, "?")
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))
    if answer == num1*num2:
        print("Correct.")
        correct = correct + 1
        questionNum = questionNum + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect. The correct answer is", answer)
        wrong = wrong + 1
        questionNum = questionNum + 1
```

The questions have the same numbers each time. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move your `random.randint` assignments *inside* the for loop:

```
for i in range(1, 9):
    num1 = random.randint(1, 49)
    num2 = random.randint(50, 100)
```

If you only call `randint` before the loop, the values of `num1` and `num2` will stay they same through each iteration. Moving it inside means you get new random numbers every time.

Also note:

- you don't need a separate `questionNum` variable, you can just use `i`; that way you don't need to increment it manually.
- you don't need to initialize `num1` or `num2` to zero at the beginning.
- Increments are a bit cleaner to write like so: `correct += 1`
- You probably want to say `print('the correct answer is', num1*num2)`  or else you'll just print their incorrect input.